# Unity - Show variable on UI Text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have some variable that can change by effect or by trigger

can some one help me to show those variable to show on Unity UI Text

for example
i want the speed variable show on Unity UI Text

here is for player status

```
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed ;
    private float MoveInput;
    public float jumpForce;
    public bool isGround;
    public Transform playerpos;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private float jumpTimeCounter;
    public float jumpTime;
    private bool isJumping;
```

and here is my powerup scripts

```
  if (!coli.CompareTag("Player")) return;

        playerMove = coli.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMove>();

        playerMove.jumpForce += jumpBonus;
        playerMove.speed += speedBonus;

        gameObject.SetActive(false);

        Destroy(this.gameObject);
```

Comment: there doesnt seem to be any code relating to setting the text in the code given. Please show what you tried

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this -

```
string name = "Jack";
int rose = 45;
string output = $"Hello {name}{rose}";
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to show the speed in a Text element, you would need to find the Text Component (makes more sense to find the component in the powerup script)

```
Text txtPlayerSpeed = GetComponent<Text>();
```

From there you can then access the text element:

```
txtPlayerSpeed.Text = "Player speed: " + playerMove.speed.ToString();
```

You want to update the text after you have made the changes to the variable.

Edit: BugFinder is correct, you haven't really attempted the question in your code, apologies since I was a little too quick on commenting.